# Two JQGrid in one page

Tags: jsp, jquery, jqgrid

i am new in ajax, jquery.

right now i am using two jqgrid for rendering data.

```
jQuery('#oldlocations').jqGrid(
            {
                url:"/",
                datatype : 'json',
                width:400,
                height:120,
                colNames:['Customer'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'custid',index:'custid',align:'center',hidden:true,sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"text",editrules:{required:true,number:true}},

                ],
                pager: '#pager1',
                viewrecords: false,
                editurl:'donothing',
                emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",
                multiselect:false,
                rowNum : 5,
                rowList : [ 5, 10, 15 ],
                loadonce:true,
                imgpath : "themes/basic/images",
                caption : ""
            });

            jQuery('#newlocations').jqGrid(
            {
                url:"/",
                datatype : 'json',
                width:400,
                height:120,
                colNames:['List Of Users Under Customers'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'custid',index:'custid',align:'center',sortable:false,hidden:true,editable:true,edittype:"text",editrules:{required:true,number:true}},

                ],
                pager: '#pager2',
                viewrecords: false,
                editurl:'donothing',
                emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",
                multiselect:false,
                rowNum : 5,
                rowList : [ 5, 10, 15 ],
                loadonce:true,
                imgpath : "themes/basic/images",
                caption : ""
            }); 


i am loading this two grids after clicking on Search button. 

 $("#searchcarbtn").click(function()
{
   jQuery("#oldlocations").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:urlstr1,mtype: 'POST',async:false ,datatype:'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid");

jQuery("#newlocations").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:urlstr2,mtype: 'POST',datatype:'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid");

}
```

The ajax calls need to be call one by one. Means my Second call is dependent on First. So First Need to be called first and after it second. Right now this is not Happening. 
Some Second call executes first. 
i tried making flag and calling second but its not working.

like.

```
var flag = 0;
if(flag == 0)
{
       first;
        flag = 1;
} 
if(flag == 1)
{
    second call. //But it is not working.
}
```

Comment: Solved By Me. I used javascript Timer.

Comment: `setTimeout` allows you to set fixed timeout only, but you prabably way to make one Ajax call *after* another one. You can use `.trigger("reloadGrid")` for the second grid inside of `loadComplete` callback of the first grid. In the case the second Ajax call will be sure after the first one. I recommend you additionally be carefully with `id` values for the data of both grids. Ids must be unique over *the whole page*. You can consider to use `idPrefix` option with different values for both grids. In the case `id` attribute of `<tr>` of grids will be set with the corresponding prefix.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for reply. but i tried loadComplete event of first grid. it was not working. i was using like imgpath : "themes/basic/images",
caption : "",
loadComplete: function () 
{
 secondCall
}
. and i also tried with gridComplete Event.

Comment: @Oleg can you give me Example ?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? `imgpath` version don't exist in jqGrid versions of last 3 years. Just replace `imgpath : "themes/basic/images",` with `loadComplete: function () {alert("in loadComplete");},` and you will see that `loadComplete` do work.